# Use the same Spring Bean instance in Apache Camel route

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I've got the following route:

```
<route id="myRoute">
    <from uri="direct:myRoute"/>
    <to uri="bean:beanA?method=processLocal"/>
    <to uri="bean:beanB?method=methodB"/>
    <to uri="bean:beanC?method=methodC"/>
    <to uri="bean:beanA?method=processGlobal"/>
</route>
```

where beanA, beanB and beanC are Spring components with **prototype** scope.
Method `processLocal` in beanA set a value to the class instance field that I then need to use in method `processGlobal`. But because the scope of my beans is prototype that field value is `null` in `processGlobal`. As far as I understand that happens because `<to uri="bean:..."/>` uses camel `ApplicationContextRegistry` class to get bean via application context that results in new bean (because of prototype).
 So, the question: is it possible to initialize bean once for a route and then use it in various `<to uri.../>` statements? Or maybe that approach is wrong and I should consider something completely different? Thanks.

Comment: See the cache option on the bean component: http://camel.apache.org/bean

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't think it would work since `Cache can be enabled if the bean in the Registry is defined as a singleton scope.` but my beans are prototypes.

Comment: You can use cache anyway. Its just unusual to only want to use prototype scoped bean as if they were singletons. They must be prototyped for a reason.